# Unable to get the values from SQLite Database in BlackBerry

Tags: sqlite, blackberry, java-me

I am trying to get the table values from the SQlite database, but it is unable to open the URI at DatabaseFactory.open().

I wrote the below code:

```
    URI myURI = null;
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try 
    {
        myURI = URI.create("/SDCard/databases/itemdb.db");

        try 
        {
            if(DatabaseFactory.exists(myURI))
            {
                Database sqliteDb = DatabaseFactory.open(myURI);
                try 
                {
                    Statement st=sqliteDb.createStatement(query);
                    st.prepare();
                    Logger.out("Grocery", "it is comin here ---- 12");
                    cursor = st.getCursor();
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "itemdb.db" database created by your application ? are you creating your database with encrypted format?  most importent is before running this code did you mount your pc file system Sd card with your simulator ? please let me know above things clearly

Comment: yes..That itemdb.db is created by my app only. And already i mounted SD card. And when i am inserting the values  in the db it is properly happening. I am able to see those values also. But only problem at the time of retrieving..

Comment: ok please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9324410/914111 link, how ever you have any doubts please come here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4014/knowledge-sharing-center-for-blackberry-and-java i will help you

Comment: Hi, is there some exception thrown on DatabaseFactory.open(myURI)? If yes, which kind of exception?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you included the error message you get when the open() call fails.

Based on this comment:

> yes..That itemdb.db is created by my app only. And already i mounted SD card. And when i am inserting the values in the db it is properly happening. I am able to see those values also. But only problem at the time of retrieving..

I am guessing you already have the database open from the insertions.  Make sure the insertion code is properly closing the database, and that you have synchronization so that the read does not try to run at the same time as the insertion code.